# Python: how to envisage the interruption of a loop before its normal end

Tags: python, loops

I have a loop running for quite a long time (several hours). It may be that the user, looking at the current results, considers the run iterations as sufficient and then wants to stop the loop before its natural end, but without interrupting the whole program (no "Ctrl+C") since some final results processing is necessary.

To do that, I added the possibility of creating a specific 'stop' file in the working directory. At each loop, the code verify if that file exists and, if that is the case, it end the loop. I do not know if this solution is efficient and whether better solutions exist.

**Example**

```
i = 0
while i < 1000 and not(path.isfile(path.join(self.wrkdir,'stop'))) :
    DoSomeStuff
    i += 1

FinalizingStuff
```

Comment: What is the condition that needs to be true in order to exit the loop?

Comment: By the way, you can use 'Ctrl+C' to stop the loop without stopping the program. Just catch the Keyboardinterrupt exception and do whatever you want

Answer (score 1):

If the only reason for not using `Ctrl+C` is that you think it will stop **all** your program, then the best solution is to use it instead of watching the files.

Simply because you can `catch` this exception (it is called `KeyboardInterrupt`) in your code as any other and do whatever you want.

```
import time

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.1)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Ok, user is pissed with our loop, go further')

finally:   
    # if some resources need to be cleaned
    pass    

print('Here we are, nothing is lost')
```

Comment: That's a nice solution. However this will interrupt the loop immediately, without completing the current iteration. Breaking out may corrupt some variable...

Comment: use finally block to make necessary cleanings